# Stuck at this induction problem

Tags: induction

I am giving it everything, but i just can't get it right.

The problem: Prove by induction that $n!>2^n$ for all integers $n\ge4$

I know how to solve the basic induction problems, but no matter what I do, I can't get this one right.

I saw how the problem is solved (schoolmate uploaded it on our class dropbox), but I just don't understand it.

The problem is, we only worked on the basics.

If someone could explain this like I'm five, that would be appreciated

Comment: I highly doubt a five years old can understand induction.....

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! Are you sure you want to start using induction ? In any case, congratulations !

Comment: [This](http://prntscr.com/4xcjri) is the solved problem by my schoolmate, using the "procedure" we used in class.

I understand that the basis is only valid for numbers bigger or equal to 4, that's more than logical to me.

Where I get stuck is the third line. We know that $n!>2^n$ is true, but how is that equal to 1 as seen in line 4?

Also some basic pointers as to how can I improve my induction problem solving would be great, cause I basically spent the whole day practicing induction and I still have an issue understanding harder problems, like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=4$, we have that $4!=24>16=2^4$, so the condition holds. Now assume it's valid for $k\geq4$: $k!>2^k$. Then
$$(k+1)!=(k+1)k!>(k+1)2^k>2\cdot2^k=2^{k+1},$$
and we hake that the condition holds for $k+1$.

Comment: How do you get from this:
$$(k+1)2^k$$
to this:

$$2\cdot2^k$$?

Comment: If $k\geq4\implies k+1>2$.